# Fast intersection of HashSet<int> and List<int>

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, intersection, hashset

I have a `HashSet<int>` and a `List<int>` (Hashset has approximately 3 Million items, List has approximately 300k items).

I currently intersect them using

```
var intersected = hashset.Intersect(list).ToArray();
```

and I wonder if there is any faster way to do so. Maybe in parallel?

Comment: Do they need to be HashSet and List?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HashSet` has a method [`IntersectWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.intersectwith?view=netcore-3.1) that is [optimized if intersection is performed between two hash sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.intersectwith?view=netcore-3.1#remarks). Using method `IntersectWith` we can intersect `HashSet` and `List` using the next approach:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> Intersect(HashSet<int> hash, List<int> list)
{
    HashSet<int> intersect = new HashSet<int>(list);
    intersect.IntersectWith(hash);
    return intersect;
}
```

---

I have measured (using [`Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netcore-3.1)) performance of your original method (`Linq Intersect`), methods proposed by @TheodorZoulias ([`HashSet Contains` and `HashSet Contains Parallel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61549744/12833205)) and my method (`HashSet IntersectWith`). Here are results:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         Method            | Min, ms | Max, ms | Avg, ms | StdDev, ms |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Linq Intersect            |   135   |   274   |   150   |     17     |
| HashSet Contains          |    25   |    44   |    26   |      2     |
| HashSet Contains Parallel |    12   |    53   |    13   |      3     |
| HashSet IntersectWith     |    57   |    89   |    61   |      4     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From the table we can see that the fastest method is `HashSet Contains Parallel` and the slowest is `Linq Intersect`.

---

Here is [complete source code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oBHU7W) that was used to measure performance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can go faster because you have already a `HashSet` in hand. The LINQ [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect) uses [a generic algorithm](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs.html#ae06318d1f5fb355), that essentially recreates a `HashSet` from scratch every time it's called. Here is a faster algorithm:

```
/// <summary>Yields all the elements of first (including duplicates) that also
/// appear in second, in the order in which they appear in first.</summary>
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Intersect<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first,
    HashSet<TSource> second)
{
    foreach (TSource element in first)
    {
        if (second.Contains(element)) yield return element;
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** Here is a parallel version of the above idea:

```
var intersected = list.AsParallel().Where(x => hashset.Contains(x)).ToArray();
```

I wouldn't expect it to be much faster, if at all, because the workload is [too granular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granularity_(parallel_computing)). The overhead of calling a lambda 300,000 times will probably overshadow any benefits of the parallelism.

Also the order of the results will not be preserved, unless the [`AsOrdered`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asordered) PLINQ method is added in the query, hurting further the performance of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

It might be faster for you to store lots of integers as a compact bit set rather than as a `HashSet` or `List` (at least if you're using `List` to store unique integers just like `HashSet`).  In this sense, there are several choices:

- The built-in [`BitArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray) stores each bit in a compact way.  As an example, if you're storing integers from 1 through 65000, `BitArray` requires about 8125 bytes of memory (as opposed to 65000 bytes if each bit were stored as an 8-bit byte).  However, `BitArray` may not be very memory-efficient if the highest set bit is very large (e.g., 3 billion), or if the set of bits is sparse (there are huge areas with set bits and/or clear bits).  You can intersect two `BitArray`s using the [`Xor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray.xor) method
- Compressed bit sets likewise store each bit in a compact way, but also compress parts of themselves to further save memory while still keeping set operations such as intersection efficient.  Examples include Elias-Fano encoding, Roaring Bitmaps, and EWAH.  See [graphs](http://people.apache.org/~jpountz/doc_id_sets4.html) comparing different implementations of compressed bit sets with uncompressed (`FixedBitSet`) in terms of performance and memory (note that they compare Java implementations, but they may still be useful in the .NET case).